# convert nc data to time series csv file at each coordinate/grid cell

Tags: r, loops, netcdf

I have the following .nc4 file and for each lat and long I would like to extract the date/time and the value. I will store each as a csv file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3j84rhbq7oo0o6/svc_MERRA2_100.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19800101.nc4?dl=0

My codes are as follows

```
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)
#open nc file 
dat.ncdf4 <- nc_open("svc_MERRA2_100.tavg1_2d_lnd_Nx.19800101.nc4")
#extracting variable of interest 
prectot <- ncvar_get(dat.ncdf4, varid="PRECSNOLAND")
# get time dimension
timeDim        <- ncvar_get(nc, "time")
# Put the time in a reader friendly format
label.time <- names(dat.ncdf4$dim)[1]
date.char <- date.char <- utcal.nc(dat.ncdf4$dim[[label.time]]$units, dat.ncdf4$dim[[label.time]]$vals, type="s")
date.POSIXlt <- strptime(date.char, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
timeDim        <- as.POSIXct(date.POSIXlt)

 # get lon/lat :
 lonDim         <- ncvar_get(dat.ncdf4, "lon")
 latDim         <- ncvar_get(dat.ncdf4, "lat")

# close netcdf file
 nc_close(dat.ncdf4)

 # The loop is to extract data for each lat and long
 for( i in seq_along(latDim))
 { 
 for(j in seq_along(lonDim))
  {

  # making the time series of date, precip, lat and long
  d1 <- data.frame(time = timeDim, prectot = prectot, latitude = latDim[i],  longitude = lonDim[j])
  write.table(d1, paste("Prp ",latDim[i],lonDim[j],".csv"), append = F, row.names= FALSE,col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
  d1 = NULL
}


   }
```

For each grid cell (latitude and longitude ) I expect four columns ( date, value, latitude and longitude) however, when I ran this code I am getting me over 60 columns with data for each csv file generated.   Your guidance would be appreciated as I can't figure out what i am doing wrong

Comment: prectot is the array of numbers, lat x long x date, and you are writing it out every time. Do you mean to select part of it for each of your 48 CSV files? You did want 48 CSV files, yes?

Comment: I want 48 csv files that will contain date, prectot and lat and long prectot is taken from.

Comment: And each file will have 24 rows? One for each time? In which case you need to take a *slice* of `prectot`, and write that, probably `prectot[i,j,]` yes? Test your code by checking what `d1` is in your loop.

Comment: thanks Mr. Spacedman, i tried this prectot[j,i,] and i get the 24 values, prectot[i,j] gives me Error in prectot[i, j] : incorrect number of dimensions... just a quick question, is any way double check that I extract the correct info?..

Comment: `prectot` is a 3 dimensional array. `dim(prectot)` gives you three numbers, so you need two commas in your subset. So `prectot[1,2,]` gets the values for the first latitude and the second longitude. Check those are as expected and in the CSV for that lat-long.

Comment: it says Error in prectot[i, j, ] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: When? Think about why it would say that. What are the values of i and j when it says that?

Answer (score 1):

With [ncks](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncks) from [NCO](http://nco.sf.net)

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncks -H -C -v three_dmn_rec_var ~/nco/data/in.nc
time[0]=1 lat[0]=-90 lon[0]=0 three_dmn_rec_var[0]=1 
time[0]=1 lat[0]=-90 lon[1]=90 three_dmn_rec_var[1]=2 
time[0]=1 lat[0]=-90 lon[2]=180 three_dmn_rec_var[2]=3 
time[0]=1 lat[0]=-90 lon[3]=270 three_dmn_rec_var[3]=4
```

and with --no_dmn_var_nm

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncks --no_dmn_var_nm -H -C -v three_dmn_rec_var ~/nco/data/in.nc
1 -90 0 1
1 -90 90 2
1 -90 180 3
1 -90 270 4
```